# Navigator.screenshot 'Undefined'

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using [this](https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot) plugin to capture screenshot in my PhoneGap application. Here is my code.

```
$('#share').click(function(){
    alert('NavigatorObj  '+navigator.screenshot+ " WindowObj " + window.plugins.screenshot);
}
```

**Problem:**

Both window.plugins.screenshot and navigator.screenshot return `Undefined`. However, window.plugins and navigator return `Objects`.

**config.xml**

```
<feature name="Screenshot">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot" />
</feature>
```

**cordova_plugins.js**

```
{
    "file":"plugins/com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot/www/Screenshot.js",
    "id": "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot.Screenshot.js",
    "clobbers": [
        "navigator.screenshot"
    ]
}

module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{

"com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": "0.1.1"
}
```

I have pasted Screenshot.java in com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot (Created the folders)

Please help. Any help would be highly recommended.

Comment: install the plugin with the CLI instead of adding it manually

Comment: @jcesarmobile I did exactly the same.

Comment: then why do you say that you "pasted Screenshot.java in com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot (Created the folders)"? that's installing the plugin manually, not from the CLI

Comment: Installing from CLI didn't paste the Java file in the directory..